# POST и OnClick на одну и ту же кнопку

Tags: javascript, php, html

Проблема в том что если я оставляю рабочим скрипт на смену атрибутов - тогда данные не приходят в файл .php который пересылает мне информацию из формы. Но спокойно меняются атрибуты у полей. Если закомментировать скрипт - тогда данные приходят и все окей, но не изменяются атрибуты у полей формы. Буду очень рад помощи, заранее - спасибо!

test.php:

```js
<?php

$_will_come = $_POST['radio'];
$token = "token_num";
$chat_id = "chat_id";
$yes = "Да";
$no = "Нет";

if($_will_come == 1){
    $arr = array('Придут или нет: ' => $yes);
    
  }elseif($_will_come == 2){
    $arr = array('Придут или нет: ' => $no);
    
  }

  foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
  };

  $sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

if ($sendToTelegram and $_will_come == 1){
  header('Location: thank.html');
}
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form_radio_group">
      <div class="form_radio_group-item">
        <input id="radio_1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
        <label for="radio_1">Придем</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_group-item">
        <input id="radio_2" type="radio" name="radio" value="2">
        <label for="radio_2">Не придем</label>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script>
      radio_1.onclick = function Input1() {
        document.getElementById('form1').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('form2').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('form3').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('form4').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('form5').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('form6').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('text_area').placeholder = "Пожелания, нюансы или интересующие вас вопросы";


      }
      radio_2.onclick = function Input2() {
        document.getElementById('form1').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('form2').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('form3').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('form4').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('form5').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('form6').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('text_area').placeholder = "А почему, расскажете?";

      }
    </script>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form1" name="answer1" placeholder="Вопрос 1" disabled>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form2" name="answer2" placeholder="Вопрос 2" disabled>
    </div>

    <p>
      <button type="submit"> Отправить <span aria-hidden ></button>
    </p>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял, но подозреваю, что это как-то связано с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1289616

Comment: @Igor Если в коде html есть скрипт который представлен в тегах <script> - отправка данных из формы в скрипт php - не происходит, но как только я уберу этот код - начинает работать php. У меня два варианта решения : из этого скрипта который в тегах, пересылать информацию  в файл php методом post или из файла php - читать данные методом  post из формы и менять атрибут у input

Comment: Я не вижу в вопросе ни одной формы, но Вы не останавливайтесь, продолжайте рассказывать Ваши теории про теги `script`.

Comment: @Igor а это что?
<div class="form_radio_group-item">
    <input id="radio_2" type="radio" name="radio" value="2">
    <label for="radio_2">Не придем</label>
  </div>

Comment: Да, это что? Блок `div` с радио-кнопкой о подписью. А форма где?

Comment: @Igor это интересует?
<form action="sender.php" class="fh5co-lead animate-box" method="POST">

Comment: Интересует минимальный пример, воспроизводящий описываемую проблему. Но кому это больше надо, мне или Вам?

Comment: @Igor -прикрепил